# Unable to display static page using NancyFX

Tags: c#, nancy, awesomium

I am not a regular developer but I have some C# programming knowledge with some basic knowledge of Winforms and ASP.NET. Over the last 2 weeks I have been trying to experiment with creating a Winform application that uses Awesomium web control and NancyFX self hosting server to build a simple desktop application.

The documentation for Awesomium and NancyFX is present on their respective sites but still seems that it requires professional/advanced developers to understand it. There are no guides or step by step demos for beginners on how to use these SDKs with C#.

My main reference has been this article - http://techny.tumblr.com/post/74609918957/arachnid-windows-gui-development-using-net-chromium

I am able to display content on the form but when i try to display MainForm.html i get a 404.

```
public class DefaultModule : NancyModule
{
    public DefaultModule(Form Form1)
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters => Response.AsFile("Static/MainForm.html");

        //Get["/"] = parameters =>
        //{
        //    //return "This works";

        //};
    }          
}
```

I have also defined the Static folder as mentioned here - [How to serve static content in Nancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270163/how-to-serve-static-content-in-nancy)

Instead of copying several lines of code here I have uploaded the code and the project at http://www.filedropper.com/awetest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to copy the `static` folder to the output folder when compiling. I'm you are running the app from that output folder (as would if you just press `F5` in Visual Studio). You can make Visual Studio copy on compile by right clicking the files you want to copy in solution explorer, choosing properties and set the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`. That should make the `static` folder appear in the output folder, so the relative paths you refer from the code are there at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue. I wrongly assumed that all files and folders are copied into the debug folder on compiling the solution.  The HTML page is displaying as expected. I can now proceed to attempt displaying an aspx page.

Comment: I would recommend trying to display a .cshtml or .sshtml page instead of a .aspx page.